# Help with Index Notation in Fourth Order Tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics

I am working on a continuum mechanics problem. I have the following relationship:

$$\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial \xi_{ik}}=-R_{ikjl}\dot{\xi}_{jl}$$

where $\xi$ is a viscous deformation gradient tensor, and $R$ is a 4th-order viscosity tensor defined as:

$$R_{ikjl}=\frac{\eta}{2}(\xi_{il}\xi_{jk}+\xi_{im}\xi_{jm}\delta_{kl})$$

My problem is that I am not used to work in index notation so I have problems with defining the tensor $R_{ikjl}$. I can say that the 2nd part of the sum would be:
$$\xi_{im}\xi_{jm}\delta_{kl}=\xi_{im}\otimes\xi_{jm}\cdot \delta_{kl}=\xi_{ik}\otimes\xi_{jl}=(\xi\otimes\xi)_{ikjl}$$

Is this correct?

If so, which operation would it be $\xi_{il}\xi_{jk}$?

I need to calculate $\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial \xi_{ik}}$ by means of known tensor operations.

$$R=\frac{\eta}{2}(?? + \xi\otimes\xi\cdot 1)\implies \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial \xi}=R:\dot{\xi}$$

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Tensors are fully specified by their components. Abstract notation for “the tensor *itself*” (which you’re not doing correctly) is pretty mathematics, but it seldom helps with actually *calculating* anything. So… sticking just to index notation, do you understand that, in the second term on the right, there is an implicit sum over the possible values for $m$?

Comment: Similarly, on the right side of the first equation, both $j$ and $l$ are summed over.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Ghoster. Yes, I understand that repeating indices imply sum. It is convenient for me to work with index-free operations like the ones I point out because I am implementing a numerical model in a finite element software whose code is much easier to work on the basis of those definitions, so I am looking for help to "translate" the index notation.

Comment: What tensor operations does the software understand?

Comment: @Ghoster: Outer product, double contraction, dot product, in short, the basic tensor operations.

Comment: $\xi_{il}\xi_{jk}$ is an outer product. You know how to recognize contractions.

Comment: But in this case the order of the indices should result in $R_{ikjl}$, and doing only that outer product results in another one $\xi_{il}\xi_{jk}=R_{iljk}$. Am I missing something? Thank you @Ghoster.

Comment: Does the software have operations for permuting indices? It’s exactly this kind of detail that makes the abstract approach annoying. Working with components, everything is perfectly clear and completely unambiguous.

Comment: Yes it can be done, I was just trying to avoid it because there are only a few papers in the context of continuum mechanics that use index notation and so I am not that familiar with it, but now I understand better its usefulness! I will have to do it in that way, thank you very much @Ghoster

Comment: I think $\xi_{ij} \xi_{kl}=\left(\xi\otimes\xi\right)_{ijkl}$ and $\xi_{im}\xi_{jm}\delta_{jl}=\left((\xi^T \xi) \otimes \mathbb{1}\right)_{ijkl}$, where $\xi^T \xi$ is the matrix you get by matrix multiplying $\xi^T$ and $\xi$ and where $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew , but the result should be $R_{ikjl}$, with that order in the indices. Can it be obtained by operations without indices?